# Failing HTTP "Post" Request from GitHub Pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, google-cloud-platform, github-pages

I'm currently building my own website that is hosted on `GitHub Pages`.

The app is built with `react.js` and what is shown here is a contact form.
The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot send a POST request to a `google cloud platform` with the cloud function service through the form on the `GitHub pages`.

Am sure the `node.js` code on GCP is working since i've used `Postman` to send a request.

With the GCP log, the function is able to parse the POST:

- [GCP Success with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0PvQ.jpg)
- [GCP Failure from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOWL.jpg)

```js
// react code
submitForm(event) {
  const {name, email, subject, message} = this.state;
  console.log("sending email...");
  console.log(JSON.stringify({name: name, email: email, subject: subject, msg: message}));
  fetch('GCP_API_HTTP', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json', },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, email: email, subject: subject, msg: message })
   }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
         return response.text();
      } else {
         this.setState({emailError: true});
         return response.text();
      }
   })
}
```

Here's what's on GCP:

```js
// GCP
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey('API_KEY');

exports.contactMe = (req, res)=> {
  let jsonBody;

  switch (req.get('Content-Type')) {
    // '{"name":"John"}'
    case 'application/json':
      jsonBody = req.body;
      break;
    // 'John'
    case 'text/plain':
      jsonBody = req.body;
      break;
    // 'name=John' in the body of a POST request (not the URL)
    case 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
      jsonBody = req.body;
      break;
  }

  let msg = {
        to: 'example@gmail.com',
        from: { email: jsonBody.email, name: jsonBody.name },
        subject: jsonBody.subject,
        text: jsonBody.msg
    };
    sgMail.send(msg);
    res.send("received!");
    res.end();
};
```

Comment: If something doesn't work, it's a really good idea to share the symptoms. What's happening? Are you getting an error in your console perhaps?

Comment: Edited the post!

Comment: You are passing a string to fetch(), not a url.

Comment: I hid my HTTP trigger from GCP with GCP_API_HTTP. But the real implementation is a URL

Comment: My first guess is that your content-type is not exactly `application/json`. Could you console.log (server-side) `req.get('Content-Type')` and `req.body`

Comment: Regardless it's not a good idea to *exactly* string-match a content-type header. If you're using express, `req.type()` is better because it handles parameters correctly.

Comment: Does this work from your local machine (not Postman, but client-side js)?

Comment: Also, it's usually a good idea to destructure the state like so `{...this.state}`

Comment: So when i do ```req.body``` in the gcp function. The one from my website comes out as ```undefined``` but the one from postman has the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite critical to understand that `GitHub Pages` publishes any static files that you push to your repository. And it's also keen to note that...

> GitHub Pages does not support server-side languages e.g. nodejs, python etc.

Since `POST` requests require server-side communication, you'll need to get an actual server host. 
[Here's a good read about Static sites by GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators)

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to solve my problem though. I'm sending a post request with the form with wufoo. works pretty well!

Comment: Does it extend GitHub Pages to work with server-side? Kindly share a link to "wufoo". I'd also like to learn how that works. Thanks.

Comment: yea here is the [link](https://www.wufoo.com/). You get 100 form fill a month which is more than enough for my needs. Once you create a form, you can chose to download the html, css, and javascript for that form. You can now play with the code and integrate it into your website.